# Using Ray's MVC demo, and want to implement TableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, mvvm

I am trying to use the code in https://github.com/raywenderlich/mvc-modern-approach 
Its very good to follow this pattern to decouple things.
But I am stuck at one point. 
I want to push another controller with attendee(cell model) details when cell's didSelect called.

How can we achieve this with generic ui ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
My question was based on the MVC demo in GitHub, and using that design pattern.

In TableViewDataSource, I added a variable

```
var actionHandler: ((Model) -> Void)?
```

And called it in didSelect.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    actionHandler?(dataSource[indexPath.row])
}
```

And in UIController

```
collectionViewDataSource.actionHandler = { [weak self] (model) in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    if let cellTapped = strongSelf.viewModel?.didSelectItem {
        cellTapped(model)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you correctly you try to avoid the InterfaceBuilder with the segue.
Did you try to use the present function from the UIViewController?

```
func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

1- In the storyboard select the viewcontroller you want to present, and under the class name put any storyboard id example: "MyViewController".

2- Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath write the following:

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
  //here you can pass any variable example: vc.variable = myVariable

  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    });
```